# issue running jmeter on mac

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Since I have got my new mac (macbook pro, catalina 10.15.4), I was trying to install jmeter and open .jmx file without any luck. Below are the things I have tried and the errors I'm seeing.

1) tried installing using homebrew (`brew install jmeter`) first

2) tried downloading zip file and unzipping from http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

In both the cases, it installs fine. But, whenever I try to open any .jmx file, I see the following error in UI

[image]

The error says

```
Problem loading XML from:'/Users/sample.jmx'. 
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup
line number         : 20
version             : 5.2.1
-------------------------------
```

I have tried downloading plugins-manager.jar and put under /lib/ext folder as mentioned https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/

But, still same issue whenever I try to open a .jmx file

Answer (score 1):

Not "any", but a .jmx file which has [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)

You need either to [download](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-casutg) the [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) bundle and unpack it to the JMeter installation folder or install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) which should be able to detect the used plugins and suggest installing missing ones

If you don't know where JMeter is installed by the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) you can re-install it with the plugins like:

```
brew install jmeter --with-plugins
```

However the lib/ext folder should be somewhere at `/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.2.1/libexec/lib/ext`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by installing jmeter 4.0 ( the package came with "Ultimate Thread Group"). It now opens .jmx files fine and I can edit as well.